# Switch programmatically to time view after the date is selected in Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

How can I switch programmatically to time view after the date is selected in Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 datetimepicker?

This is the code:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
  // After the date is selected, I would like to switch to time view automatically / programmatically
});
```

I searched in the [documentation](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/) and the web, but couldn't find an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the documentation and the way that picker is structured, I don't believe that behaviour is possible, without a *lot* of modification of the library.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it seems that I have to choose another datetime picker instead of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

though this question is pretty old, I wouldn't say that this is impossible and that it requires modifying the library.

Here is the working code:

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 80px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
  var $picker = $("#datetimepicker1");
  $picker.on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
    // After the date is selected, I would like to switch to time view automatically / programmatically
    if (!e.oldDate && $picker.datetimepicker('useCurrent')) {
      // First time ever. If useCurrent option is set to true (default), do nothing
      // because the first date is selected automatically.
      return;
    }
    else if (
      e.oldDate &&
      e.date &&
      (e.oldDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') === e.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    ) {
      // Date didn't change (time did).
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1 [data-action="togglePicker"]').click();
    }, 300); // With a mini delay so that the animation doesn't fire right-away.
  });
});
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ta5j6v7/2/).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, although I already switched to pickadate.js, it might be useful for others.